# Getting rows which include a value with MySQL

Tags: sql, mysql

I have a MySQL query which gets including some vars like that:

*messages TABLE receiver cols*

- *user1 rows : 1,3,5*
- *user2 rows : 2,3*
- *user3 rows : 1,4*

I want to get rows which includes '3' value. So I will get 'user1' and 'user2'.

I tried that but naturally it doesn't work.

```
mysql_query("SELECT * FROM messages WHERE receiver='3'");
```

How can I do this?

Comment: Please give us some more information about the fields in the messages table. Most obviously we need to know the datatype of 'receiver'. Is it a string (try @Sarfaz' answer) or is it numeric (try my (@lexu) answer)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
mysql_query("SELECT * FROM messages WHERE receiver like '%3%'");
```

Comment: What if a row contains "13,30,33"? Your query will match it and it should not.

Comment: @Asaph: If we are only interested in `3`, we could do like `mysql_query("SELECT * FROM messages WHERE receiver like '%,3,%'");` because as can be seen each value is separated by a comma.

Comment: @Sarfaz: That strategy fails on the following inputs "3" or "3,7" or "1,3".

Comment: @Asaph: For that reason i put in the query in my answer to detect even that and only OP can tell how exactly his value are.

Comment: @Sarfraz: You could use Regular Expressions (http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/regexp.html) to match a 'isolated' 3 in a string .. this might calm @Asaph a bit :-) ..

Comment: @lexu: Agreed and yes Asaph has raised good point unless OP needs it how he says. Thanks for that link, this should be helpful to OP too.

Comment: @Sarfaz: I still suspect that receiver is a numeric FK into another table .. only the OP can tell!

Comment: @lexu: I have doubt that OP has not constructed his tables correctly like mico says.

Comment: @Sarfaz: You might very well be right ... I hope he/she tells us soon what the table structure is like.

Answer (score 2):

Like others have mentioned, trying to search denormalized data "1,2,3,4,44,5,55" in a relational database is not a good approach. Relational databases are built for handling normalized data.

You could.. note, could split the string into a subset ([Split function in MySQL](http://blog.fedecarg.com/2009/02/22/mysql-split-string-function/)), then do a IN-search operation, but this is neither a recommended approach.

The best way to tackle the problem is from the top. Since trying to build around it, instead of actually fixing it, is never a good way to go.

The solution; Normalize the data.

```
Message
- [PK] Id
- Body...

Reciever
- [PK] Id
- Name...

MessageReceiver
- [FK] MessageId
- [FK] ReceiverId
```

Having this table structure, you could easily query:

```
SELECT M.* FROM MessageReceiver MR
INNER JOIN Message M ON M.Id=MR.MessageId
WHERE MR.ReceiverId=3
```

Solving it this way will save you a lot of headache in the future.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way would be to restructure your database.

Have a table `messages` with `id`, `text`, etc., a table `receivers` with `id`, `name` and a table `msg2rec` (or however you wanna call it) with `id_msg` and `id_rec`.

That way you can do:

```
SELECT m.text, r.name
FROM msg2rec m2r 
LEFT JOIN messages m ON m2r.id_msg = m.id 
LEFT JOIN receivers r ON m2r.id_rec = r.id 
WHERE m2r.id_rec = 3
```

---

Alternatively, if you keep your structure you should use:

```
 SELECT text 
 FROM messages 
 WHERE rec RLIKE (",3,") OR rec RLIKE("^3,") OR rec RLIKE(",3$")
```

There's probably one single regexp that does the same as the 3 above, but I can't figure it out right now.
Anyway, I would go with the first option: cleaner, easier to mantain and to work with